# How to capture and assert the value populated via a datepicker using selenium

Tags: jquery-ui, selenium-webdriver, datepicker

I'm trying to test the date-picker to this [site](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). and selected a date , which resulted in populating a text field with the selected date.

Now I wanted to validate, if the date selected is as expected. I was able to do up to selecting the date and populating the text field.

But when trying to validate the value, I'm getting back spaces from text field.

How can I capture the value populated by date-picker and assert the same ?

I have done to this below mentioned code, but it didn't help me.

```
driver.get(" https://www.jqueryui.com");
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Datepicker")).click();
WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.className("demo-frame"));
driver.switchTo().frame(element1);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='datepicker']")).click();        
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Next')]")).click();
List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/table/tbody/tr/td"));
int count = element.size();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
{
    String data = element.get(i).getText();
    if("2".equals(data))
    {
        element.get(i).click();
        break;
    }
}

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='datepicker']")).click();
WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='datepicker']"));

String value = element2.getText();
Assert.assertEquals("04/02/2017",value);
```

My expectation is value will hold `04/02/2017`, as 2 was selected. Apparently DOM is not updated. So, what should I be doing here to capture and assert the value selected ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `JavascriptExecutor` for getting value of selected date. Following piece of code should work in your case.

```
 WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='datepicker']"));
 JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 String date = (String) jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].value", element2);
 System.out.println("Date:- " + date);
 Assert.assertEquals("04/02/2017", date);
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation:** Use `.getAttribute()` to get the value of `date selection` and pass attribute as `value` For more details on this refer below code.

For Explanation refer below image also.

[image]

Try this below code, I have done this solution using `array method`.

```
driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));        //Move inside iframe.
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
Thread.sleep(2000);

WebElement date_texbox = driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker"));    
date_texbox.click();                                             //Date-picker text-box element
Thread.sleep(2000);
WebElement date = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Next']/span"));  
date.click();                                                     //Move to the April Month 2017 from date picker.

int[] array_date = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};   //Create int array for dates.

int k = 1;                                       //K refers to tr tag
int l = 7;                                       //l refers to td tag
for(int j=0;j<array_date.length;j++)
{
    if(l==8)
    {
        k++;
        l=1;        
    }

    if(k==2 & l==1)
    {
        System.out.println("Date = 04/02/2017");
        String second_april_2017 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a")).getText();
        System.out.println(second_april_2017);  

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr["+k+"]/td["+l+"]/a")).click();

        String get_date_value = driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker")).getAttribute("value");
        System.out.println("Date Selection Value = " +get_date_value);
        Assert.assertEquals("04/02/2017", get_date_value);                          //verify condition for this 04/02/2017 date.
    }

    System.out.println(k);
    System.out.println(l);

    if(!(k==2 & l==1))     //if date selection is 04/02/2017 then this condition will not execute.
    {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr["+k+"]/td["+l+"]/a")).click();     // pass array value of k and l to the xpath.
    }

    Thread.sleep(2500);
    date_texbox.click();
    Thread.sleep(2500);
    l++;
}

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();    //Move out side to the frame.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker")).getAttribute("value");`

Try something like this

```
        driver.get(" https://www.jqueryui.com");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Datepicker")).click();
        WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.className("demo-frame"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(element1);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='datepicker']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Next')]")).click();
        List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/table/tbody/tr/td"));
        int count = element.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            String data = element.get(i).getText();
            if ("2".equals(data)) {
                element.get(i).click();
                break;
            }
        }

        String value=driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker")).getAttribute("value");
        System.out.println("value is" +value);
        Assert.assertEquals("04/02/2017", value);
```